# Nvidia drivers installation in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

Much confusion and conflicting information regarding Nvidia driver installation in Ubuntu. In my case Ubuntu-mate. 
My goal is to use my Linux workstation exclusively for GPU rendering, so installing Nvidia drivers properly is of utmost importance!

All I 've learned so far is
- *don't use Nouveau!*
and
- *most problems I've encountered are due to improperly installed Nvidia drivers!*

The problem with most installation guides is they act as recipes, without actually telling you WHY this is a better approach or WHY you might try an alternative.
Ok Rant over :)

A quick google search turns up the following 5 recent (within the past year) installation guides for Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu.
A very simple breakdown seems to be between what I would call 'fully manual' methods using the command line (link #3 below) vs some combination of  PPA + using the Software & Updates menu.

**Question #1**
Why PPA, and in what way might this be 'better' than a fully manual install?
Link #5 below suggests PPA is untested ( so does that mean beta and possibly avoid?)

**Question #2**
If using a fully manual install (link #3) should I simply choose the most recent driver version?
The reason i ask is in link#1 (official guide?) it says that the actual version

> "depends on the version of Ubuntu one is using, and what graphics card
>   one has installed."

**Question #3**
Is it one way or the other? ie If you install your driver manually should you avoid using the Software & Updates > Other Drivers window to avoid conflicts?

**Question #4**
If unsure what driver version you have currently installed, how do you properly remove ALL installed graphics drivers to start from scratch?

1  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia (using Software & Updates - additional drivers method only)

2  https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-install-graphics-card-drivers-in-ubuntu/3228
(both auto using Software & Updates and manual, but no explanation as to why manual)

3 https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus 
(manual using sudo apt-get install)

4 http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-nvidia-367-27-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-0415-10.html 
(manual using ppa +sudo apt-get install)

5 http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html 
(using PPA + Software & Updates window, suggests PPA is untested)

Comment: Why don't you use the one which comes along with the distribution?

Comment: Go to `Additional Drivers` and select the Nvidia one.